# If $f$ is meromorphic in some region, why can't $\frac{f'}{f}$ have any essential singularities in that region?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, singularity, meromorphic-functions

It is stated in the Wikipedia article on the argument principle that the only singularities of $\frac{f'}{f}$ are the zeros and poles of $f$ itself.

It is not at all clear that there are no essential singularities; suppose $f$ has an essential singularity - surely so would its derivative, and so how can it be that the quotient merely has a tame pole, instead of an essential singularity.

My only thought is this:

$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{d}{dz}\ln(f(z))$$

And so the only essential singularities of the quotient would be the essential singularities of $\ln$, which is essentially singular (is this correct terminology?) at $z=0$, but at $z=0$ the quotient has a pole, therefore we only have a pole. This however is massively unrigorous! Is this correct? How does one prove it formally?

Comment: *By definition* of a meromorphic function, $f$ has only poles (and no essential singularities).

Comment: @MartinR So when Wikipedia said "It can be shown"... they really meant: "It follows by definition"?

Comment: You have to show that the only singularities of $f'/f$ occur at zeros and poles of $f$, but that is more or less trivial.

Comment: @MartinR I know how to classify a singularity, but I don't know how to abstractly take a possible singularity and show by contradiction (or other means) that it is not essential

Comment: Sorry, but it is not yet clear to me where the problem is. If $f$ is meromorphic in an domain $D$ then it is holomorphic in $D$ with the possible exception of isolated points, where $f$ has a pole. Where should the essential singularities come from?

Comment: @MartinR That's my intuition too, but I feared some essential singularity could arise from some point where $f'(z)$ is a pole/zero and $f$ is a zero/pole and that this would create "bad" behaviour. Clearly I have no idea how to formally attack this! I know how to examine a Laurent series but the Laurent series of $f'/f$ was too tricky for me to compute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is meromorphic in a domain $D \subset \Bbb C$ if there is a (possibly empty) set $P \subset D$ such that

- every point in $P$ is isolated in $D$,
- $f$ is holomorphic in $D \setminus P$, and
- $f$ has a pole at every point in $P$.

Now assume that $f$ is not identically zero, and let $Z$ be the (possibly empty) set of the zeros of $f$. (We know from the identity principle that every point in $Z$ is isolated in $D$.)

The $h = f'/f$ is holomorphic in $D \setminus (P \cup Z)$.

At a $k$-fold pole of $f$ at $a \in P$ is
$$
 f(z) = (z-a)^{-k} g(z)
$$
where $g$ is holomorphic and non-zero in a neighborhood of $z=a$. Therefore
$$
 h(z) = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{-k}{z-a} + \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}
$$
in a neighborhood of $z=a$, so that $h$ has a simple pole at $z=a$.

Similarly, at a $l$-fold zero of $f$ at $b \in Z$ is
$$
 f(z) = (z-b)^{l} h(z)
$$
where $h$ is holomorphic and non-zero in a neighborhood of $z=b$. Therefore
$$
 h(z) = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{l}{z-b} + \frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}
$$
in a neighborhood of $z=b$, so that $h$ again has a simple pole at $z=b$.

So the only singularities of $f'/f$ occur at the zeros and poles of $f$, and these singularities are poles.

Comment: Thanks, I was just overthinking it I suppose